# Export the fetched database data to PDF or Excel format

Tags: php, html

I want to export fetched data from my database to pdf format or excel format.
Can someone help me out with a simple example?

Comment: Have you looked at any of the myriad of libraries for generating PDF or Excel files in PHP?

Comment: No sir, i am beginner in programming can you please explain me bit

Comment: Start by giving us a clue what you'd already done, because your question is too broad for a simple answer. Have you managed to fetch data from the database yet?

Comment: Yes sir i am able to fetch data from database

Comment: @MarkBaker hi sir can you please help me out

Answer (score 0):

It would be easiest to use CSV which means Comma Separated Values and that's exactly what it is.

For example:

```
Name,Surname,Birth year
John,Doe,1990
```

It will become a table if opened with Excel or other Calc software.

Also it is a good practice to have text surrounded by quotes, because it's required if the text contains commas.

So final version:

```
"Name","Surname","Birth year"
"John","Doe","1990"
```

The file should be in .csv format.

Comment: Can you please explain me with small example